# How to stop objects being pixelated in Gear VR app?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gear-vr

I imported the Vuforia sample for gear vr in unity and replaced the objects with blender objects. Now when in my scene I put the object very close to the camera it works alright. But when I am in the Ar mode or I look form a distance at the object the edges of the objects seem very pixelatex. And move a little bit.(Blink). I have the anti aliassing on the hightes it can be but that didn´t change a thing. The blinking would indicate to me that the depth buffer is confused but since i am new to unity I have no idea what to do about that. I also read about mipmapping, that the resulution of the textures might be false. But I use materials which are colored so I can´t imagine which settings to change. Please help! Any suggestion would be very welcome!

Comment: I think you can change the material shader to the shader from vuforia package

Answer (score 0):

You should set your rendering from the default 50% to 100%. Do you have any screen shots it will help.

[How to do it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cgL3.png)

Comment: How would I do that? I can´t find the setting. When I go to the playersettings on Resolution and Presentation It says that they are oberridden by virtual reality support

Comment: Click on my how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oculus SDK 1.6+, you might want to check the OVRManager and make sure that "Use Recommanded MSAA" is turned off. You can also try adjust the "Min & Max Render Scale".

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrya1.png